# Currently how big is it for R?

Tags: r, file, size

I have a question regarding: how big is a file for R currently? I had some configuration changes on the computer that would be upgrade, but I notice that R did not benefit from that.

I went from Windows 7 to Windows 1, the desktop because 16gb of RAM and processor i7. I am using version 4.2 of R that no longer supports the Memory.limit () function, which I used a lot.

I would like to limit the RAM available to R, because I realize that it has frozen the PC and I need to turn off in the energy, something I had never done before using R.

As an example, I mention that I am a file of 13 million lines with 15 columns, I am doing merge files of files using `left_join (x, y, by = c ("Year", "id")`, the file have 412,000 lines and 139 columns. Is this absurd?

I can fragment it, but I would like to run everything together. The final question would be, which big can be a file for R today?

Comment: We cannot know if this is absurd because we cannot know how many rows the result of your join will have. Joins can easily blow up your memory. You can check the size of an object with `object.size`. However, does your system have swap memory and it's "freezing" when RAM is exhausted and it switches to swap memory? What is the task manager telling you? Memory is managed by the OS. You can't set limits from inside R (anymore).

Comment: Also, a large join can take time (10 minutes or more). I recommend switching to using package data.table as it's more efficient.